# Spring Boot @ResponseStatus not returning HTTP message

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, error-handling, httpresponse

I've a problem returning HTTP Messages when an exception is thrown. I'm using @ResponseStatus annotation to handle the HTTP Status code, it shows ok but the message is ignored.

Custom Exception:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, reason = "An error ocurred while trying to 
retrieve the instruments.")
public class InstrumentsNotFoundException extends RuntimeException { 

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InstrumentsNotFoundException.class);

public InstrumentsNotFoundException(String errorMessage) {
    super(errorMessage);
    logger.error(errorMessage);
}
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping({ "/portfolio/" })
public List<Instrument> getAll() {
    try {
        List<Instrument> instruments= portfolioYieldProcessor.getPortfolio();
        return instruments;
    } catch(RuntimeException e) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(
                  HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Sorry, an error occurred, please try again later.", e);
    }   
}
```

HttpMessage

[image: Http Response]

Comment: you have already an exception which is annotated with@ResponseStatus. Why don't you throw that itself?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Starting from SpringBoot 2.3 this is the default behavior, as you can see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#changes-to-the-default-error-pages-content).

Assuming you are using spring 2.3+

```
server.error.include-message=always
```

in your application.properties will do the trick for you.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about this setting.

Comment: Nice, perfect, thanks. Advice for Kotlin newbies like me: it goes on application.properties file (at least on my case).

Comment: I've updated the answer to better explain where to put the fix. ;)